Why doesn't Annotated[str, T] work while Annotated[T, str] works well?
I have a project where user need to use Annotated[str, MyType()] a lot. In order to simplify it, I try to create a generic type
T = TypeVar('T')
CustomUrl = Annotated[str, T]

But I get this error when I try to use it this way:
CustomUrl[MyData()]

# TypeError: typing.Annotated[str, ~T] is not a generic class

I have no idea why this happens, and it works well when I reverse the order to
CustomUrl[T, str]

But that's not what I want. Is there any way to make it work?
My use case is to have user declare a dataclass and it will generate a UI schema automatically, for example
# pseudo code

@dataclass
class TaskArgs:
  input_text: Annotated[str, {'multiline': True}]
  input_file: Annotated[str, {'multifiles': True}]

Update
I have try the following answer:
from typing import Annotated, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class CustomeUrl(Annotated[str, T]):
    ...

c: CustomeUrl = 's'

The problem is the last expression raise the error:
Expression of type "Literal['s']" is incompatible with declared type "CustomeUrl"
  "Literal['s']" is incompatible with "CustomeUrl"

The reason I choose Annotated is to ensure the type check is valid so I don't think it solves my issue.

First, the syntax to create a TypeVar is TypeVar('T') (parentheses, not square brackets). Second, T is used at type checking time to represent a type, whereas MyData() is a dynamic runtime value, not a type. What exactly are you trying to do?

@InSync fix typo and add use case to the question

TLDR: T is (at runtime) treated as an annotation when passed as a "metadata" argument.
Your attempt to parametrize Annotated[str, T] fails at both type-checking time and runtime due to the following reasons:
Type checking time
Annotated allows any kinds of values to be specified for the second argument and later, but a TypeVar only represents a type. You can't pass a dynamic value like MyData() to CustomUrl and expect type checkers to accept it as the substitution of T.
This is explicitly stated in neither the specs nor the docs, but it pretty much can be inferred (emphasis mine):

Using Annotated[T, x] as an annotation still allows for static typechecking of T, as type checkers will simply ignore the metadata x.

Runtime
Annotated[str, T] calls _AnnotatedAlias(origin=str, metadata=(T,)), which in turn calls _GenericAlias(origin=str, args=str), eventually leading to .__parameters__ being (). This makes the returned value (an instance of the _AnnotatedAlias class) non-parametrizable.
Solution
You are better off sticking to Annotated:
@dataclass
class TaskArgs:
  input_text: Annotated[str, some_call()]
  input_file: Annotated[str, another_call()]

Lengthy? Maybe. Type-checker-friendly? Yes. Interpreter-friendly? Also yes.
